What is the Typescript equivalent of Rust's Self?
In Rust, I can refer to the current type without explicitly mentioning the type:
struct MyClass {
    foo: String,
    bar: String
}

impl MyClass {
    pub fn new(foo: String, bar: String) -> Self {
        return Self { foo, bar };
    }

    pub fn fork(&self, foo: String) -> Self {
        return Self::new(foo, self.bar.clone());
    }

    pub fn log(&self) {
        println!("Hello {} from {}", self.foo, self.bar);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let c1 = MyClass::new(String::from("lorem"), String::from("ipsum"));
    let c2 = c1.fork(String::from("foobar"));

    c1.log();
    c2.log();
}

How do I do the same in Typescript?
class MyClass {
    private readonly foo: string;
    private readonly bar: string;

    public constructor(foo: string, bar: string) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    /*
    It works if the function is static, but that defeats the purpose of the function

    public static fork(foo: string) {
        return new this();
    }
    */

    public fork(foo: string) {
        // Error: This expression is not constructible. Type 'Function' has no construct signatures.
        return new this.constructor(foo, this.bar);
    }

    public log() {
        console.log(`Hello ${this.foo} from ${this.bar}`);
    }
}

const c1 = new MyClass("lorem", "ipsum");
const c2 = c1.fork("foobar");

c1.log();
c2.log();

The obvious way return new this.constructor() fails because this.constructor is a Function, which is not a constructor.
The compiler is mad but the Javascript works, so I imagine there's a handy Typescript builtin utility type for exactly this purpose, but I can't figure out which one to use.

Thanks for that link, it led me to more discussions and I think the answer is still "getting the types right is impossible". Many workarounds, but still none to address the fact that I don't want to have to type the class name - e.g., the code can be copy-pasted to any class and still work.
